# Jtable disable hover selected row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have a little problem with jtable :

[image]

when i click on the **Appliquer** utton, he clera all the table except the **in-write** cell, so i need to unset **in-write** mode??

that how it look like when i have clicked **Appliquer** button :
[image]

Comment: Do you want to know how to disable a cell? Not understanding your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still editing the data in the cell so it has not bee saved to the TableModel yet.

See [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a couple of solutions that will make sure the data is saved when you click a button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
table.clearSelection();
```

Or for a particular cell use.

```
columnModel.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```